# cakephp & nusoap - Function ("my_function") is not a valid method for this service

Tags: php, cakephp, soap, nusoap

I have taken over an application from a previous developer, and there was some code which was half finished using Nusoap, I am getting the error:

```
Call to register_donation() web service failed due to an exception: 
Function ("register_donation") is not a valid method for this service
```

The application is built on: `CakePHP 1.2.10` & using `nuSoap 0.9.5`.

I have already `ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);` (This doesnt help.)

My code is below (I shortened it for readability), Am I processing this response correctly?
(The code was taken over by myself from a previous developer).

The Pastebin (of the full code) is here: [PasteBin Link](http://pastebin.com/Cv1Nx32W)

A shortened version is below for a glance over, the full version is in the pastebin link above.

```
<?php
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);

class ServicesController extends AppController
{
var $uses = array("Donation");
var $components = array( "Email", "MatchingEvents" );

function registerDonation($donation = null){
    $this->log('hit registerDonation', 'donation');
    $this->autoRender = false;
    App::import('Vendor','nusoap');
    Configure::write('debug',0);
    Configure::write('Session.start', false);

    //init soap server
    $server = new soap_server();

    $endpoint = 'http://new.mysite.com/services/registerDonation';

    //initialize WSDL support
    $server->configureWSDL('donations', 'urn:donations', $endpoint);

    //setup service type
    $server->wsdl->addComplexType(
        'DonationResult',
        'complexType',
        'struct',
        'all',
        '',
        array(
            'success' => array('name' => 'success', 'type' => 'xsd:boolean'),
            'msg' => array('name' => 'msg', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
            'error_number' => array('name' => 'error_number', 'type' => 'xsd:string')
        )
    );

    //register the method to expose
    $server->register('register_donation',
        array('ct_number' => 'xsd:string', 'project_id' => 'xsd:int', 'donation_amount' => 'xsd:decimal',
            // Stripped all other params
        ),
        array(
            'result' => 'tns:DonationResult'
        ),
        'urn:donations',
        'urn:donations#register_donation',
        'rpc',
        'encoded',
        'Accepts the results of a donation to a charity or project on the  site'
    );

    //This inner function is registered and then called (keep within outer function!)
    function register_donation(
        // Pass in all the params (Stripped for readability)
        $ct_number = null, $project_id = null, $donation_amount = null
    ){
        // This function is never hit!.. its not registered, why?
        $this->log('hit #3-register_donation called!', 'donation');
        $return = $this->Donation->add(array(
            'unique_id' => $unique_id,
            'ct_number' => $ct_number,
            'project_id' => $project_id,
            'donation_amount' => $donation_amount,
            // Pass in all other params, (Stripped for readability)
        ));

        // Process that request
        $log = $this->Donation->log . 'Result: ' . $return['msg'] . "\n";
        $this->log( $log, 'donation' );
        if ( isset($this->Donation->matching['events']) )
        {
            //Reserved donations should already have had their events handled
            $this->MatchingEvents->handle($this->Donation->matching, !$this->Donation->matching['reserved']);
        }
        if ( !empty($this->Donation->cacheSaved) )
            $this->_sendDonationEmails($this->Donation->cacheSaved);
        return $return;
    }

    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']) ? $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] : '';
    $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
}

function _sendDonationEmails($donation)
{
    // Send the emails
}
}

?>
```

If there is any more information I can provide, please let me know.

**To Summarise:** How do I process a nusoap response coming from a external source.
 Any debugging ideas, hints & tips or solution will be rewarded (+1!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code posted there's a function named `registerDonation` inside a controller named `ServicesController`. Inside that function there is another function called `register_donation` (This obviously doesn't make sense [Old Code]).

Remove the function named `register_donation` out of the `registerDonation` method and place it as a method inside the `ServicesContoller`.

Then change the following line (where you register the function to expose).

From: `$server->register('register_donation',`
To:     `$server->register('ServicesController.register_donation',`

So you're calling `class.method` as opposed to method only (This would work in  PHP4 procedural programming, but in OOP, you need to specify the `controller.method` when exposing the function).

---

### Having other problems?

**Q: CakePHP & nuSOAP is not hitting my controller/method, but redirects to app/webroot**
**A:** Using CakePHP 1.2, I found when it did not have a services model (because it wasn't 
technically required), The request does not hit the controller. So if you're having this issue, create a model for your controller, even if you're not using it. For your reference, here a modal example:

```
<?php // You may not need this modal, but cakephp requires it to be there.
class Services extends AppModel {
   public $name = 'Services';
   public $useTable = false;
}
?>
```

**Q:What URL should I be receiving responses to?**
**A:** The URL you set your response to hit must include `?wsdl`.
So.. for eg: you have a controller named `SOAPController` and method named `process`.
In CakePHP, your URL would look like this: `mydomain.com/SOAP/process`.
So your `WSDL` is located at `mydomain.com/SOAP/process?wsdl`. Make sure your callback URL is set to this (including the `wsdl`).

**Q: How do I debug SOAP requests/responses using CakePHP?**
**A:** CakePHP has a logging feature which proved invaluable in debugging `SOAP`. In your controller (or modal) you can use:

```
$this->log('your message or variable', 'name_of_file_to_save_to);
```

You can use this through your `SOAP` request or response to see what parts are being hit/called and debugging variables (eg: `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`).

#### Q: My WSDL location is shown as `domain.com/app/webroot` when I visit the SOAP page.

**A:** I thought this was the issue causing all the problems, Looking at the source code `Nusoap` uses `PHP_SELF` to get the current script (which in cakePHP is `app/webroot/index.php`), Don't worry about this, you can access the `wsdl` by appending the URL with `?wsdl`, This will show you your generated `WSDL` file, You don't need to worry about fixing this. Its not interfering with your `SOAP` request whatsoever, It's merely there for your convenience.

#### Q: My SOAP address location is showing 'domain.com/app/webroot/index.php`

**A:** This was a issue I fixed by including the `$endpoint` in the `configureWSDL()`.

```
//Set our endpoint, Replace with your URL
$endpoint = 'http://yourdomain.com/controller/method';

//initialize WSDL support - Include the $endpoint.
$server->configureWSDL('donations', 'urn:donations', $endpoint);

// Now your Soap Address Location should be what you set as the $endpoint
```